# Can a doc file or excel file can edit and save to the database with react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to changes something in the doc file and save it into the database. Are there any packages that can help me to solve this?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This is a very unusual use case for react.js. If you want to learn react, start with a simpler project. If your main goal is to write a program to manipulate doc files, there are various ways to do that too. But it depends a lot on what environment you are working in. For example, Microsoft Office 365 has scripting support built in.